# Programatically add view to match parent to fill TableLayout

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I am trying to dynamically create a View to act as a spacer between table rows however my view is only going as wide as the text even though I am trying to have them match parent.

[image]

I am dynamically adding to the TableLayout with

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);    

tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
tr.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
tr.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

layout.setPadding(15, 15, 10, 15);

TextView description = new TextView(this);
description.setText(row.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));
description.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.black));
description.setTextSize(25);

TextView dateCreated = new TextView(this);
dateCreated.setText("Date Created: " + row.getString(TAG_DATEADDED).replace("\\", ""));
dateCreated.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.black));
dateCreated.setTextSize(20);

TextView reportType = new TextView(this);
reportType.setText("Report Type: " + row.getString(TAG_REPTYPE));
reportType.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.black));
reportType.setTextSize(20);

View view = new View(this);
view.setMinimumHeight(2);
view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.black));
view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

layout.addView(description);
layout.addView(dateCreated);
layout.addView(reportType);
layout.addView(view);

tr.addView(layout);

existingReports.addView(tr);
```

and I define my TableLayout in my XML with

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_numExistingReports"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txt_numExistingReports"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_numExistingReports"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/home"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/home">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        android:id="@+id/existingReports"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The scrollview width is Wrap Content...try with Match Parent

Comment: That didn't have any affect unfortunately